# moto g2 XT1068 not turning on

Tags: rooting, root-access, twrp, motorola-moto-g2, supersu

I was rooting my XT1068,after rooting root checker displayed root accesses is not complete.i thought it was because of old superSU so downloaded latest superSU v2.67 installed it in fastboot and rebooted my phone. and from them my phone is stuck in warning display [warning bootloader unlocked] phone not turning on... plz juys help.. and if any one has stock fermwear to restore plz direct me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try relocking the bootloader. If it doesn't help, flashing a stock firmware is the last chance.

Download the file from *[here](https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20G%20%282nd%20gen-2014%29/Stock/XT1068/)*. Unzip the file and use [RSD Lite](http://rsdlite.com/) to flash to the phone.